# Having a lot of trouble with Yii2 QueryBuilder

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2

```
    public function getOrderItemStatus($magentoorderitemid) {
    $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(["COALESCE(ShipTracking.ShipCarrier, '') AS ShipCarrier", "COALESCE(ShipTracking.ShipVendor, '') AS ShipMethod", "COALESCE(ShipTracking.ShipCarrier, '') AS ShipCarrier","COALESCE(ShipTracking.TrackingNumber, '') AS TrackingNumber"])
        ->from('OrderDetails')
        ->leftJoin('PickTicketOrders','PickTicketOrders.OrderId = OrderDetails.OrderId')
        ->leftJoin('ShipTracking', 'ShipTracking.PickTicketId = PickTicketOrders.Id')
        ->leftJoin('Products', 'Products.ISBN = OrderDetails.ISBN')
        ->where('OrderDetails.MagentoOrderItemId=:magentoorderitemid', [':magentoorderitemid' => $magentoorderitemid]);
    $result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($query)->execute();
    return $result;
}
```

Even when I remove the `joins` and the `where`, and I change the select to `*`. It doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
  ->select(["COALESCE(ShipTracking.ShipCarrier, '') AS ShipCarrier", "COALESCE(ShipTracking.ShipVendor, '') AS ShipMethod", "COALESCE(ShipTracking.ShipCarrier, '') AS ShipCarrier","COALESCE(ShipTracking.TrackingNumber, '') AS TrackingNumber"])
  ->from('OrderDetails')
  ->leftJoin('PickTicketOrders','PickTicketOrders.OrderId = OrderDetails.OrderId')
  ->leftJoin('ShipTracking', 'ShipTracking.PickTicketId = PickTicketOrders.Id')
  ->leftJoin('Products', 'Products.ISBN = OrderDetails.ISBN')
  ->where('OrderDetails.MagentoOrderItemId=:magentoorderitemid', [':magentoorderitemid' => $magentoorderitemid]);
  $command = $query->createCommand();
  $result = $command->queryAll();
```

Use this query in this way

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following and it works

```
        $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(["COALESCE(ShipTracking.ShipCarrier, '') AS ShipCarrier", "COALESCE(ShipTracking.ShipVendor, '') AS ShipMethod", "COALESCE(ShipTracking.ShipCarrier, '') AS ShipCarrier","COALESCE(ShipTracking.TrackingNumber, '') AS TrackingNumber"])
        ->from('OrderDetails')
        ->leftJoin('PickTicketOrders','PickTicketOrders.OrderId = OrderDetails.OrderId')
        ->leftJoin('ShipTracking', 'ShipTracking.PickTicketId = PickTicketOrders.Id')
        ->leftJoin('Products', 'Products.ISBN = OrderDetails.ISBN')
        ->where('OrderDetails.MagentoOrderItemId=:magentoorderitemid', [':magentoorderitemid' => $magentoorderitemid]);
    $result = $query->all();
```